# how can i run time in my java application without threads?

Tags: java.util.date

I want to get current time to my java app and want to make time running.If i use thread class  my app is getting slower and slower. How can i aware this? Is there any method of running time?

---

Here is my code:-

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            while (true) {



             String s=new Date().toString();                           
             String tim=s.split(" ")[3];





            }

        }

    }).start();
```

Comment: Besides being useless code that will most probably peg a core at 100% usage .. what's the problem/question?

Comment: Dude - you need some sleep....

Comment: Sorry -- does not compute.  You do not need to use a thread to get the current time.